# Python Program to define a function for matrix and obtain values of matrices separately in as lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to make a function that makes a matrix whenever called.

> Problem1: When I try to make a 2x3 or 3x2 and fill it: `IndexError:
>   list index out of range`. **Solved by Haminaa**

```
def mtx():
    m=int(raw_input("Rows"))
    n=int(raw_input("Col"))
    a=[[0 for i in range(m)]for j in range(n)]
    l=[]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            s=a[i][j]=int(raw_input("Fill"))
            l.append(s)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(j+1):
            print a[i][j], '\t',
        print
```

You must have seen a list in the code, that is for obtaining the list of inputs.
I want to get the values of m and n separately for each matrix. And also the list.

For example, I want to get this

```
mtx()
m1=m
n1=n
l1=l
mtx()
m2=m
n2=n
l2=l
```

> Problem2(a): Error that m is not defined(so are n and l).

Also, I tried to take m and n out of the definition and as a parameter. So I am able to get m and n.

```
def mtx(m,n):
    a=[[0 for i in range(m)]for j in range(n)]
    l=[]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            s=a[i][j]=int(raw_input("Fill"))
            l.append(s)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(j+1):
            print a[i][j], '\t',
        print

m1=int(raw_input("Rows"))
n1=int(raw_input("Col"))
mtx(m1,n1)
m2=int(raw_input("Rows"))
n2=int(raw_input("Col"))
mtx(m2,n2)
```

> Problem2(b):But is it possible to get list l?
>
> If problem2(a) is solved, there'd be no problem2(b).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second problem. I've tried your code (with the list comprehension reversed) and it printed a bunch of values that I gave as "Fill" input. Is this not what you want? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Haminaa I want to get the values of m and n. Like when the function is called, it asks user to input m and n, and creates list for inputs via "Fill". So, I want these values of m,n and l so I can use them in future for applications like addition and multiplication of matrices. For example, for multiplication, I need to make sure that number of columns in first matrix = to number of rows in second.(i.e. m1=n2). Then I will use the list to multiply and create an answer matrix.

Comment: It seems that in your code, values of `m` and `n` are already stored in `n1`, `m1`, etc. However, variables that you define are only defined inside the function. To define them outside the function you can use `return` at the end of your function. I've updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing your list comprehension the wrong way round. If you want `m` to indicate the number of rows and `n` to indicate the number of columns, you should do:

```
a=[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(m)]
```

Regarding your 2nd problem, you can make your function return list `l` using a `return` statement at the end of your function. Also the last `print` does not do anything in your example so I removed it:

```
def mtx(m,n):
    a=[[0 for i in range(n)]for j in range(m)]
    l=[]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            s=a[i][j]=int(raw_input("Fill"))
            l.append(s)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(j+1):
            print a[i][j], '\t',
    return l
```

If you then call your function:

```
my_list = mtx(m1,m2)
```

list `l` is now assigned to `my_list`.

Comment: I did try return but didn't know that we have to assign variable to get l. Thanks for that. Also, btw, that print maybe isn't useless as I also want to print the matrix as a matrix.